# Why does LLVM add two extra instructions for the same program?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, llvm, instructions

I am compiling this C program and comparing the generated assembly code:

```
int main(){ return 0; }
```

[GCC](http://pastebin.com/mPEffN7n) gives this main function (`cc hello.c -S`):

```
_main:
LFB2:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

[LLVM](http://pastebin.com/B2qiucVy) gives this main function (`clang hello.c -S`):

```
_main:
Leh_func_begin0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end0:
```

---

What are `movl  $0, -4(%rbp)` and `popq %rbp` needed for? Moving something on the stack and popping it directly afterwards seems useless to me.

Comment: It seems a little unfair to compare compilers' assembly output without using the optimizer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, they're comparable. Leave is a high level instruction:

From the Intel manual:

```
16-bit: C9 LEAVE A Valid Valid Set SP to BP, then pop BP.
32-bit: C9 LEAVE A N.E. Valid Set ESP to EBP, then pop EBP.
64-bit: C9 LEAVE A Valid N.E. Set RSP to RBP, then pop RBP.
```

basically, leave is equivalent to

```
movq %rbp, %rsp
popq %rbp
```

Comment: As I understand it, `leave` isn't more or less expensive than the identical `mov`/`pop`, but `enter` is ridiculously more expensive than just `add` ing to the stack pointer.

Comment: That would explain why I've almost never seen a compiler produce `enter` instructions...

Answer (score 9):

The `movl    $0, -4(%rbp)` instruction is dead, because this is unoptimized code. Try passing in `-O` to both compilers to see what changes.

Comment: Chris look for the "code" quotations when you write bits of code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like LLVM is using a traditional function prolog/epilog, whereas GCC is taking advantage of the fact that the entry point doesn't need to clean up

Comment: Ahah, so GCC always assumes my the main function is the starting point, but LLVM does not?

Comment: No, gcc is taking advantage of the fact that the function body was empty.

Comment: I disagree on both counts. `eax` is being set, the epilog still happens via `leave`. The most efficient implementation is `movl $0, $eax` then `ret`, not bothering with the stack at all. That's what gcc does on `-O3`, which is truly taking advantage of a practically empty function. As is, the two are comparable, although I don't know how expensive leave is compared to mov/pop.

Comment: `leave` used to be much more expensive than `mov`/`pop`.  I'm not sure what the status is now -- I imagine it has a lot to do with which specific core you're dealing with.  To be fair `enter`/`leave` also does more than `mov`/`push`/`pop`/etc. will.  Specifically they cover nested procedures with a single high-level instruction (something not needed for the C blight).

Comment: @Matt Joiner: I'm not a huge fan of the BCPL-descended branch of the computer language tree.  ;)

Comment: The only notable derivative of BCPL is C, so I presume you don't like anything derived from C? C++, Java, C#, PHP etc.?